# How to prove that $e^\pi>\pi^e$

Tags: calculus

How can one prove that $e^\pi>\pi^e$ ? Should I use logarithms or something like that? Or is there a gentle smart way of proving so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** 
 $e^n>1+n$ given $n>0$. Now see what happens when $n=\dfrac \pi e-1$.

Comment: $n$ seems an un-natural choice of variable, no? (+1 though)

Comment: @anaconda  Un-natural? Really? :p

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would be a good pun as well as a good point :)